# How do I disable zooming on text input focus?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, browser, chrome-for-android

I know there are certain tricks to disable zooming when making a web page, but how do I disable zoom on focus on my device?

I have Paranoid Android and the Xposed Framework, so, I know anything is possible.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the answer is that you can't.

That's confirmed pretty conclusively by [this bug report/feature request thread in the Chrome development forum](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=181560). The thread goes all the way back to March 2014, and recent posts indicate that a means of disabling this behavior has not been implemented.

Sadly, recent indications are that the dev team is disinclined to implement such a setting in the future. Despite input from several people providing examples of how this feature can be an impediment, and requesting a setting to disable it, this response from a developer says that they avoid adding new settings, and they'd rather work on making it "less annoying":

> #12: I haven't really noticed it zooming in on mobile sites.  When it does, we can consider that a bug, but I don't think a modal ban is the right approach.  I'd rather continuing tuning the policy so that it doesn't trigger when inappropriate.  Note also that the same code deals with animating the scroll position around when the on-screen-keyboard would cover the form field.  That behavior definitely desirable to preserve even on mobile sites.
>
> #13: We generally try to avoid adding settings in Chrome; we'd rather tune this so it's less annoying for all users, not just the ones who discover the setting.  We already made a few improvements to make this trigger less frequently since the bug was originally filed; we might benefit from loosening it further to tolerate further zoom levels.

The bottom line is that it sounds like it's not possible and it's not going to be.

You can disable this behavior by using a browser other than Chrome, at least for any sites where you don't want automatic zooming on focus.

Comment: I'm currently looking for an XPosed module that will help out. I'll post my findings once I've done enough searching

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out for FireFox users:

1. In the Firefox browser for Android, navigate to `about:config`.
2. Find the line named `formhelper.autozoom`
3. Set to `false`

This is especially beneficial to navigating websites in desktop mode,  without that nasty input zoom.

Comment: `formhelper.mode` can also be set to 0 to prevent the scrolling to form elements. Between these two settings you get rid of most of the misfeatures associated with mobile browsers.

Comment: Ah! ysh, firefox goes brr.....

Answer (score 1):

That's a "solution" for the question asked, but it's a quite efficient workaround.

What helped me was:

1. Open mobile browser "settings"
2. Go to "accessibility"
3. Turn on the "show distance from display on main menu" option on (or whatever it's called on your browser)
4. When on site, set the distance from display to minimum. In my case it was 50%.

That setting altered the display to contain more content on my smartphone screen so zoom auto zoom didn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

My solution that may help was to install an app called [Windows Manipulator](https://www.xda-developers.com/window-manipulator/) on my Android phone and then set the DPI significantly lower.  This gives me enough screen real estate (albeit with a significantly smaller font).

This seems to keep Chrome from zooming on focus as often.  I also switched to FlashFox Pro browser which does not zoom on focus frequently.

These 2 fixes combined have eliminated my complaints.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]! Thank you for your contribution, could you also add the link for the apps you mentioned on this answer?