# Disable cursor and automatic zoom into textbox in Firefox

Tags: keyboard, firefox-for-android, zooming

I have Firefox installed in my Android devices (phone and tablet). Everytime I open a new site (say [bookzz.org](http://bookzz.org/) ), the cursor is automatically in the textbox, the page is zoomed in and the on-screen keyboard pops open. This is extremely annoying and though it seems simple, I have no idea how to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/113142) that **doesn't work** on `Firefox 49.0`

Comment: Can you provide URL of a site exhibiting same behavior? On bookzz.org disabling jquery.com gets rid of the issue.

Comment: https://watchseriesfree.to/